# Getting OSM Data (e.g. maxSpeed) for route that is returned from OSM Routing

Tags: r, openstreetmap, routing

Is there any way to use the Openstreetmap Routing Service and use the returned route to get access to all the tags that the OSM data has for this route?

Specifically, I am thinking about querying the route from Location A to Location B and I want to inspect the properties of the roads (maxSpeed, bycicle, the type of the street...) that the request to the routing service returned.

I am using the r-package `osrm`.

The R code I am using to get a route looks like this:

```
p1 = c(12, 46) 
p2 = c(12.1, 46.1)
route = osrm::osrmRoute(p1, p2, returnclass = "sf", overview="full")
```

And I'd like to get the underlying OSM-Information for e.g. this route

Comment: Any chance of a sample returned route or code to generate one?

Comment: sure, just a second

Comment: http://project-osrm.org/docs/v5.24.0/api/#routestep-object and the rest of the API docs doesn't seem to let you get an OSM ID for an OSM way. You can get OSM ids for *points* via the annotation system.  I may be missing something though.

Comment: Four years ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52234323/get-way-id-from-osrm-matching-service

Comment: In theory, you could grab small overlapping polygons along the route and parse the data, but yuck

Comment: @Spacedman Thanks a lot for the hint!:)